# My animation using Raphael is lagging, why?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, raphael

I've set up a [demo illustrating animation on a circle shape](http://jsfiddle.net/YEqTe/2/), and the circle seem to falter while rendering. What's causing the animation to be laggy? How can I make it smooth?

I tried to replace the use of `setInterval()` with a call to `animate()`, as can be seen in the commented code, to no avail.

```js
var WINDOW_HEIGHT = 400;
var WINDOW_WIDTH = 600;

var paper = Raphael(0, 0, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);

Circle = function(paper, x, y, r, color) {
    this.paper = paper;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.r = r;
    this.color = color;
    this.xd = 1;
    this.yd = 1;
    this.elem;
}

Circle.prototype.create = function() {
    this.elem = this.paper.circle(this.x, this.y, this.r);
    this.elem.attr("fill", this.color);
    this.elem.attr("stroke", this.color);
}

Circle.prototype.move = function() {

    if (this.x < 0 || this.x > WINDOW_WIDTH) {
        this.xd = -this.xd;
    }
    if (this.y < 0 || this.y > WINDOW_HEIGHT) {
        this.yd = -this.yd;
    }
    this.x += this.xd;
    this.y += this.yd;

    this.elem.attr("cx", this.x);
    this.elem.attr("cy", this.y);
}

Circle.prototype.animate = function(x, y) {
    this.elem.animate({
        cx: x,
        cy: y
    }, 1000, "linear");
}

var circle = new Circle(paper, 0, 0, 30, "#f00");

circle.create();

window.setInterval(function() {
    circle.move();
}, 1);

//circle.animate(300, 300);​​
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a side-effect of your `setInterval` with an interval of 1 millisecond. Browsers can't really handle that. Instead, calculate position based on time, and only request a new frame when the last one is done:

```
var _requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame || function(f) { setTimeout(f, 16); };

var lastUpdate = new Date().getTime();

var update = function() {
    // How many milliseconds has it been since the last update?
    var now = new Date().getTime();
    var d = now - lastUpdate;
    lastUpdate = now;

    // Now, move the ball based on the difference.
    // Looping is not the right way to go about this, mind.
    var amountBallMoved = d / 33;

    for(var i = 0; i < amountBallMoved; i++)
        circle.move();

    // And finally, request the next animation frame.
    _requestAnimationFrame(update);
};

update();​​​
```

[Here's an updated jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/YEqTe/3/)